# Borrar datos de una tabla Java

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

Preciso ayuda para entender mejor. Necesito borrar de una interfaz de datos de una tabla que lleno desde una DB, sólo la filas de la tabla sin tocar la DB. Para eso tengo pensado hacer un botón llamado `clear`.

De esta forma lleno las celdas de la tabla.

```
button1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
  public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Se ha seleccionado el botón");
    TableItem item;
                 
    try {
      while (rs.next()) {
        item = new TableItem(tabla, SWT.NONE);
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
          item.setText(i - 1, rs.getString(i));
        }
      }

    } catch (SQLException e1) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
  }
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probé con ese código, pero me borra las columnas y yo quiero borrar las filas.

```
while ( tabla.getColumnCount() > 0 ) {
  tabla.getColumns()[ 0 ].dispose();
}
```

Estoy pensando en un pseudo código donde realice una corrida y compare, si la celda es diferente de `null` que borre los datos.

> - *mientras(->  <--!=null) and (->  <--.next)*
> - *creo un objeto de la tabla por ejemplo item*
> - *para (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber)//recorrer*
> - *si (item!=null) item.dispose();*

```
while (item.getData() != null) {
  item = new TableItem(tabla, SWT.NONE);
  for (int i = 1; i < columnsNumber;) {
    if (item != null) {
      item.dispose();
      // tabla.getColumnCount();
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Gracias para quien se pueda tomar su tiempo.

Comment: Usa el método `remove()`, Ej. `tabla.remove(1);`.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! @Sal puede utilizar el método. No se mucho sobre swt. Lo que me sucede ahora que luego de eliminar las filas no puedo volver a llenar las celdas con los datos de la db. Utilizando el método el botón conectar.